# Django throws TypeError when trying to use auth LoginView

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

I'm following [this tutorial](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/authentication_authorization/) (it's a good one!) to try and learn to use Django. I'm using python3x and Django2.1, so now and then I need to iron some wrinkles due to the different versions, but so far so good.

Right now everything worked until I tried to add the security (have users to log in in order to access some features). At first I got

```
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'
```

which was kind of weird but could solve it by changing

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
```

to 
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.LoginView, name='login'),

in urls.py. Now I can get to my blog homepage. Unfortunately, when I try to add a new post (functionality that requires to be logged in) *not being logged in* I'm getting quite a different error:

```
    TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

and this one I cannot figure it out. Why does it show and how do I solve it?

The URL when I get this error is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/post/new/
```

my site's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.LoginView, name='login'),
    #importa las urls de la app 'blog' (hay que crear el fichero urls.py en blog/)
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    #esta dirige la raiz del site a una app concreta

]
```

my app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
        url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
        url(r'^drafts/$', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
    ]
```

and my app's views.py

```
from django.utils  import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

@login_required
def post_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.save()
                return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def post_edit(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.save()
                return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = PostForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def post_draft_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_draft_list.html', {'posts': posts})

@login_required
def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)

@login_required
def post_remove(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.delete()
    return redirect('post_list')
```

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: Try using `views.LoginView.as_view()` instead of `views.LoginView`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! If you post the response, I'll accept it right away ;)